# Chapa y pintura en otros idiomas

Tags: traducción

Tenemos un debate súper importante en la empresa sobre una expresión cotidiana española.

Normalmente decimos **"chapa y pintura"** cuando arreglamos la parte estética de algo sin arreglar su corazón, como por ejemplo, pintando un coche y cambiándole las partes dañadas exteriores para venderlo por mayor valor.

Esta misma expresión en inglés podría ser **put lipstick on a pig**, pero es muy vulgar y no me veo utilizándola en una reunión importante.

¿Qué maneras más o menos formales hay de decir **"Chapa y pintura"** en inglés ?

Comment: "You can put lipstick on a pig. It's still a pig" fue la frase usada por Obama en la campaña presidencial en 2008 y ganó. Puede que te parezca vulgar pero aparentemente para los norteamericanos es perfectamente natural y puede ser usada en público. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnkI0lyIzccu

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Spanish. It is looking for an expression in English. There is no Spanish to discuss here, only English expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some plausable alternatives, maybe not perfect:

- [spruce up](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/spruce%20up) — *Bonhag really wanted Cowperwood to **spruce up** and show what he could do, socially or otherwise.*
- [make presentable](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/make%20presentable) — *A good-looking fellow, too; only wanting a little training to **make presentable** anywhere.*

neither of these are specific to selling a thing, nor repairing damage as much as just fixing the appearance.

I have the suspicion that *the fact* that a phrase refers to the sale of a thing in english would make it necessarily somewhat more vulgar than any similar phrase that does not.

Comment: isn't make presentable more simple by using "dandy" ?

Answer (score 1):

"You can put lipstick on a pig. It's still a pig" fue la frase usada por Obama en la campaña presidencial en 2008 y ganó.

Puede que te parezca vulgar pero aparentemente para los norteamericanos es perfectamente natural y puede ser usada en público por lo que creo que es la mejor opción para "chapa y pintura".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnkI0lyIzccu

De acuerdo a [Time magazine: A Brief History Of: 'Putting Lipstick on a Pig'](http://content.time.com/time/nation/article/0,8599,1840392,00.html) la definición y uso en inglés es el mismo uso de "chapa y pintura" en España

> It's a phrase common in the car sales industry, used to describe
>   taking a hunk of junk, brushing on a fresh coat of paint and selling
>   it for full price.